# Removing core data and establishing relationships using codable

Tags: swift, core-data, one-to-many, codable

Here is a simplified version of JSON I'm dealing with

```
"groups": [
    {
        "id": 
        "vehicle": {
            "id": 
            "name":
         }
    }
 ]
```

So basically the JSON is a list of groups, which have vehicles. Currently, I use JSON response to create and store the group and vehicle models in core data and fetch from core data to populate the views. The vehicle has a one-to-many relationship with the group, i.e. a vehicle can belong to different groups. Right now, I create group core data objects and then create vehicle core data objects from the JSON(OR fetch them based on ids if they're already there in the core data store and update them with the new data) and then assign the vehicle to the respective group. Note that vehicle has a set of groups and just by assigning the vehicle to the groups the inverse relationship gets populated  So basically I have groups and vehicle types saved in core data, with the one to many relationships populated. But now I need to remove core data and populate the views using the JSON response directly using codable. So there are 2 challenges:

1. How to define the inverse relationship of vehicle to groups.
2. I need a list of all vehicles to populate the views, so how to decode all the vehicles from the JSON.

Can I just make the groups and vehicles conform to codable, decode
to get all the groups objects, and iterate through them to get all
the vehicles inside them, populating the inverse relation from
vehicle to the groups i.e for each vehicle keep on adding the group id to a property that is a set of groups.

I might not have framed the question well, but essentially I want the best way to move from core data to codable where I can get a list of groups and vehicles and also populate the one to many relationships between them,

Comment: To be clear, you have a many-to-many relationship between group and vehicle, right? A group can contain many vehicles and a vehicle can belong to many groups?

Comment: hey @JoakimDanielson, a group contains only one vehicle, but the vehicle can belong to different groups

Comment: Then you shouldn't call it a group since a group implies something that holds many elements of some kind. So a vehicle has a property `groups` that is an array of `Group` then. And a group has a `vehicle` property that is of type `Vehicle`

Comment: There are some other properties that I have omitted that makes it a group, I've just posted a simplified version but yeah I get your point. Yes you're right above the above.

Comment: One adjustment to my previous comment, since a group belongs to only one vehicle it should not need a property for vehicle.

Comment: Ah a group doesn't belong to a vehicle, it has a vehicle property. A vehicle belongs to a group, as you can see from the json structure, vehicle is inside a group. The catch is vehicle can belong to different groups. That is a one(vehicle) to many(groups) relationship I have in core data right now.

Comment: Basically, I need to get the following to replicate the core data setup I have now:
1. List of all groups (which can just be done by conforming groups and vehicles to codable and decoding the JSON)
2. List of all vehicles with an extra property of groups that tells me all the groups it belongs to: not sure how to get this

Comment: Can you explain why you need to remove Core Data?  That feature - automatic management of inverse relationships - might be justification enough to keep it, even if you don't want to persist the data.

Comment: I don't think you should look so much at the current Core Data design. Make your structs as have been discussed and store them as json. `struct Vehicle: Codable { let groups: [Group] ...}` and `struct Group: Codable {...}`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson As I mentioned my requirements above, I need a list of groups and vehicles(with a property telling me the list of groups it belongs to). How do I achieve that in a smart way using codable. Note that the vehicle JSON is nested inside the group JSON.

Comment: @pbasdf There are multiple reasons for it, doesn't really make sense to discuss here as it is out of the scope of the problem statement

Comment: _"Note that the vehicle JSON is nested inside the group JSON"_, are you saying the format of the json is already decided?

Comment: Yes, it is the snippet I have shared above.

Comment: Then I don't really know what we are discussing if you already have the design of your json. Good luck.

Comment: We're discussing how to decode that JSON as I've mentioned in my requirements above, maybe I'm not framing the question correctly. Thanks for your time!